# İmage Picker Crash in Flutter

Tags: flutter, crashlytics, imagepicker, xiaomi, oppo

I am using Image Picker library. Although my code works normally another devices, Xiaomi and oppo devices crash after taking a picture.
I tried using the libraries "image_picker: 0.8.9" and "image_pickers: 2.0.4+1". I am getting the same error on both.

This is how an error comes to Firebase crashlytics.

Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError
PlatformException(already_active, Image picker is already active, null, null)

Can anyone help with this error?